# Find the source files of Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, indexing

i mean i want to see the source file of the main page.
when i click right click and choice the option view source, so i want to find
the "body" of the file,and edit it physical, which folder can i find it ?
thanks friends.

Comment: Theme source or core source? Like the dashboard/admin or the public/theme?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress's HTML is generated by PHP in conjunction with CSS, so look in your active theme folder in wp-content/themes/yourtheme. You'll find all the parts of a WordPress theme: [Using Themes « WordPress Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Themes)

Answer (score 1):

WordPress runs on the server -- the "source" you're viewing from your browser is client-side, and is essentially the output of the WordPress PHP code that generates the pages (and some CSS transforms). In order to see the PHP source, you'll have to download it from WordPress's website yourself or look at your WP installation directory on your server.